# flutter : Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: ___gxx_personality_v0

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am running a flutter project on the simulator but getting the error of **Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12.
Exited (sigterm)
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: ___gxx_personality_v0**. I have tried all solutions of previously asked questions but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem with `flutter_sound`.
It seems to be a linker issue.
[This](https://github.com/facebookarchive/pop/issues/25#issuecomment-41652577) solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 6):

In your Flutter project in Android Studio, follow below steps

- Open any file in (ios) package
- Then click on the link (Open iOS module in Xcode) that appears on the top right
- When Xcode opens, double click on the (Runner) from the left menu, then many taps will appears on the right section.
- Open the (Build Settings) tap and search for the text (Other Linker Flags)
- Double click on its value and press the (+) icon and add the following "-lc++"
- Close Xcode and try to run the application again from Android Studio